# Tkinter canvas not scrolling

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar, ttk

Tkinter experts, I'm having trouble getting a Canvas to scroll.  This is my second GUI, and I've done something similar before, so I don't know what I'm doing wrong.  I'd appreciate any help you can offer.

Here's a minimal version of what I'm trying to do.  I'm using python 3.4.3 on Windows 10.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as tk_font
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import random


def get_string_var(parent, value=''):
    var = tk.StringVar(parent)
    var.set(value)
    return var


class SummaryFrame(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, **kwargs)

        var_names = ['label_'+str(num) for num in range(1, 20)]
        self.vars = {}
        for name in var_names:
            self.vars[name] = get_string_var(self)

        self._add_summary_labels(self, self.vars, 1)

    @staticmethod
    def _add_summary_labels(frame, vars, start_row):
        current_row = start_row
        for name in vars:
            tk.Label(frame, text=name, anchor=tk.N+tk.W).grid(row=current_row, column=0, sticky=tk.N+tk.S+tk.W+tk.E)
            text_label = tk.Label(frame, wraplength=200, textvariable=vars[name], anchor=tk.N+tk.W, justify=tk.LEFT)
            text_label.grid(row=current_row, column=1, sticky=tk.W)
            current_row += 1

    def set_summary_fields(self, info):
        for name in info:
            if name in self.vars:
                self.vars[name].set(info[name])


class OuterFrame(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, **kwargs)

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self)
        scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(self, orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
        self.summary = SummaryFrame(self.canvas)
        self.summary.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
        self.canvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
        scrollbar.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.Y, expand=1)

        label_text = {}
        for i in range(1, 20):
            label_text['label_'+str(i)] = "information " * random.randint(1, 20)
        self.set_fields(label_text)

    def set_fields(self, info):
        self.summary.set_summary_fields(info)
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=(1, 1, self.summary.winfo_width(), self.summary.winfo_height()))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    frame = OuterFrame(root)
    frame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
    root.mainloop()
```

The scrollbar should change when the contents of the inner SummaryFrame expands, but doesn't.  It remains grayed out and inoperable.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you are configuring the scrollregion to be one pixel by one pixel.

You are configuring the `scrollregion` based on the width and height of the `self.summary`, but you are doing this before the window has a chance to be mapped to the screen. The width and height, therefore, are both one.

You need to wait for the window to be drawn before computing the width and height of the window.

Comment: Thanks.  Your answer got me pointed in the right direction.  I had forgotten to call self.canvas.create_window, so the summary frame never got mapped onto the canvas.  Between that and binding to '<Configure>' on the canvas, it's working now.